# Arrays as input name testing in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, laravel-5.1

I'm writing some tests for a form I've written in Laravel 5.1 but I'm getting an error saying:

```
Symfony\Component\CssSelector\Exception\SyntaxErrorException: Expected identifier or "*", but <number "1" at 11> found.
```

The issue is that I'm using 'array' names for some of my fields.

It's a series of questions and I'm using the question ID to map answers:

```
<label>Your answer for question 1?
    <textarea name="question[1]"></textarea>
<label>
<label>Your answer for question 2?
    <textarea name="question[2]"></textarea>
<label>
```

Then my test looks like this:

```
$response = $this->actingAs($user)
        ->visit('/application/project/1/1')
        ->type('This is a new title', 'title')
        ->type('My Question one Answer', 'question[1]')
        ->press('Save & Next Page');
```

I assume I need to present `question[1]` differently but I can't see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way you can get around this is by using the `submitForm` method.

```
$input = [
    'title' => 'This is my new title',
    'question[1]' => 'My Question one answer'
];
$response = $this->actingAs($user)
    ->visit('/application/project/1/1')
    ->submitForm('Save & Next Page', $input);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much.